Is it safe to move Windows system partitions with gparted
My disk has the following partitions structure:

old windows recovery partition
EFI
main windows system partition
new Windows recovery partition
free space

I'd like to extend the main partition to use all the free space.
I can probably safely move new recovery partition to the end and use all the free space from the end of the disk.
Can I also safely move old recovery partition in front of main partition with gparted?
It would move both EFI and windows main partition. Will windows still boot?
After moves I'd like to get:

EFI
windows main partition
free space
old windows recovery partition
new Windows recovery partition

So I could extend the main partition with free space and old recovery:

EFI
windows main partition (extended)
new recovery partition


Delete the second WinRE partition using these instructions; this will allow you to extend the Windows partition into the free space. There is no simple solution to delete the old WinRE partition and move the EFI partition.  I would dare say its not possible.

I would just delete the "old windows recovery partition" and leave the free space unused. Most likely it is less than 1GB and thus not worth the effort (and the risk). Thus I would delete all RE partitions, extend the main partition (leave 1GB after the main partition for the RE) and then recreate the RE partition.
